# How do I reconcile these two definitions of acceleration?

Tags: kinematics, differential-geometry, acceleration, differentiation, calculus

How do I reconcile these two definitions of acceleration?

$$a=\frac{d\bar{v}}{dt}=(\frac{dv^k}{dt}+v^i v^j \Gamma^k_{ij})\bar{e}_k \tag{1}$$

and

$$a^k=v^{\small\beta} \nabla_{\small\beta} v^k.\tag{2}$$

I tried doing it for gravity in polar coordinates.

$v^r=gt$

$r=\frac{1}{2} gt^2$

This clearly works for the first formula because

$a=\frac{d\bar{v}}{dt}=(\frac{dv^r}{dt}+v^r v^r \Gamma^r_{rr})\bar{e}_r $

and

$\Gamma^r_{rr}=0$

Now, the second formula.

$a^r = v^r \nabla_r v^r $ because $v^\theta =0$

$a^r = v^r (\frac{\partial v^r}{\partial r}) $

?

$= \frac{\partial r}{\partial t}  (\frac{\partial v^r}{\partial r})=\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} $

Is this correct?

If so, how should I do it in general?

Comment: Looks more or less right to me, what do you think is the issue?

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational I thought the second formula looked wrong because of the units. It looks like it has units of [velocity][acceleration]. so I tried to show they are the same in the general case but I couldn't do it. so I did the simplest case and it seemed to work. but i'm never sure of my calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general,

\begin{align}
v^\beta \nabla_\beta v^k = v^\beta (\partial_\beta v^k +\Gamma^k_{\beta \alpha}v^\alpha) = v^\beta \partial_\beta v^k + v^\beta v^\alpha \Gamma^k_{\beta \alpha}.
\end{align}
The only thing left to realise is that
\begin{align}
v^\beta \partial_\beta v^k = \frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial t}\frac{\partial v^k}{\partial x^\beta} = \frac{\partial v^k}{\partial t},
\end{align}
(if you're not happy with the last step, perhaps convince yourself that you'd be happy to go from the right hand side to the left hand side) and this is exactly what you have in the first expression (just contracted with a basis).